# pyhs2 error connective to kerberos enabled hive

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, pyhive

I am trying to connect to hive using python 2(miniconda2 installation ).
Below is the code I am trying-

```
connection = hive.connect(host='psvlxihpnn1', port= '10000', authMechanism='KERBEROS', user='***',password='****', configuration={'krb_host': 'psvlxihpnn1', 'krb_service': 'ITEDM'} )
```

kerberos host is installed on the same host machine and has service name 'ITEDM'
Strangely, I am getting below error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/export/home/itedm/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/pyhs2/__init__.py", line 7, in connect
  File "/export/home/itedm/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/pyhs2/connections.py", line 46, in __init__
  File "/export/home/itedm/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 66, in open
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-1) SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server krbtgt/INFORMATICA.COM@ITEDM not found in Kerberos database)
```

I am not passing 'krbtgt' as user, not sure why this error is coming.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The syntax is `service/host@REALM` and "krbtgt" means "not actually an *authorisation* request to a *service* but an *authentication* request to get a KeRBeros Ticket-Granting-Ticket (*krb tgt*)"

Comment: And in the case of a TGT, the "service principal" should read as `krbtgt/REALM@REALM` (just create a ticket in the default cache with `kinit someuser@SOME.REALM` and check the result with `klist`) so you clearly have a problem.

Comment: On the other hand, a TGT for your user is required, but the Hive JDBC URL should explicitly mention the Kerberos principal of the **Hive service** i.e. typically `hive/hs2.host.fqdn@REALM` so you should read carefully the documentation about this ugly Python library (if any).

Comment: I am going thru this link  for Pyhs2 library...https://github.com/BradRuderman/pyhs2/blob/master/pyhs2/connections.py... It seems I have a problem with the kerberos principal which I am checking with the admin.. is their any better python library that could connect to kerberos enabled hive in python?

Answer (score 0):

This connection string will work as long as the user running the script has a valid kerberos ticket:

```
import pyhs2

with pyhs2.connect(host='beeline_host',
                    port=10000,
                    authMechanism="KERBEROS") as conn:

with conn.cursor() as cur:
        print cur.getDatabases()
```

Username, password and any other configuration parameters are not passed through the KDC.